# does anyone know how the proactive recovery works in PBFT?

Tags: hyperledger, distributed-system, consensus, hyperledger-sawtooth

can anyone provide a simple explanation on proactive recovery in PBFT , i have read the paper and i could not understand anything, so does anyone know how the proactive recovery works in PBFT ?